# Override a package source but only on specific platforms

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller, python-packaging, python-poetry

I'm building an application in Python that eventually gets built to an executable via pyInstaller which supports multiple platforms. However, one of my package dependencies (Pillow) does not provide a wheel for `universal2`, and I need a `universal2` package in order to build a portable distribution via pyInstaller.

At present I am building the wheel locally (using `delocate`) and overriding Poetry by doing something like:

```
poetry install
poetry run pip install build/*_universal2.whl --force-reinstall
```

but I would prefer a solution that exists entirely within Poetry, if possible.

Alternately, is there a package source I can point to which can automatically provide me a latest fused-to-`universal2` build of my dependencies (Pillow in particular)?